# Java Web servlet: writing plain text on an existing html template file

Tags: html, servlets

I have Webservlet in Java (Eclpise EE) that dynamically prints a text as follows:

```
@WebServlet("/test")
public class MyApp extends HttpServlet 
{
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(ProcessEvent());
}
```

I have designed a simple template (`default.html`) file with a color background and an image on one side. The html is part of the project in Eclipse.

How can I get the application to print on this default.html file instead of printing the text plain as is on blank page via `out.println()` ?

Comment: Where have you put `default.html`?

Comment: In WebContent folder. I could also rename it to default.jsp or put it anywhere if necessary.

Comment: Isn't this what a JSP would be used for?

Comment: Could you share name of your web-app?

Comment: my web-app name is mywebapp.

Comment: In ajax call: do out.write rather than out.println

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a super simple web application where a `JSP` page would be used as view technology and `Servlet` would supply the business logic, following example might help you:

Step 1: Create following `sample.jsp` in `/WebContent/WEB-INF/templates` of  Eclipse's `Dynamic Web Project`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sample Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<b>Time Now:</b> ${requestScope["time"]}
</body>
</html>
```

Step 2: Create following `Servlet` to supply the business logic for the `JSP` page:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/test")
public class MyApp extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public MyApp() {
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 

    request.setAttribute("time", new Date()); // 'time' would be  shown on JSP page             
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/templates/sample.jsp");      
    view.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Step 3: Call the above `Servlet` by hitting following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/test
```

The output is as shown below:

[image]

Comment: This looks very good and straight-forward. Where would my actual code from above then go -- that is, `out.println(ProcessEvent());`?

Comment: `ProcessEvent()` is simply a method that returns a string. `String ProcessEvent(){ String test_out = "Example: the time now."; return test_out; }`

Comment: Have accepted as answer. Could share your .jsp page? I will like to see where the attribute "time" is on the source.

Comment: I have already shared the `sample.jsp`. You will find it at `Step 1`.

Comment: hey Sanjeev thanks! I must also say the structure you have provided is highly invaluable and will help me in designing web technologies down the line. Cheers!

Comment: How to make this for dynamic table from database?